# Parse error with theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parsing, widget, themes

I've developed a local site with wordpress and the theme Lugada.
All is OK on local. I've transfered all data on ovh.

When I want to see what is done I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /homez.705/cadeauxd/www/wp-content/themes/lugada/include/widget.php on
>   line 1

When I add empty rows at the beginning it's the same thing: on line 1

Here's the file :

```
<?php
class RecentPost_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /* Register widget with WordPress. */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'recentpost_widget', // Base ID
            '(Lugada) Recent Post with Thumbnail', // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'lugada recent post with post-thumbnail support widget.', 'lugada' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /* Front-end display of widget. */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $rcnumber =  $instance['rcnumber'] ;

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        ?>
        <?php 
        echo '<ul>';
        echo lugada_display_recent_posts($rcnumber); 
        echo '</ul>';?>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /* Sanitize widget form values as they are saved. */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['rcnumber'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['rcnumber'] );

        return $instance;
    }

    /* Back-end widget form. */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( $instance ) {
            $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
            $rcnumber = esc_attr( $instance[ 'rcnumber' ] );
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'Recent post', 'lugada' );
            $rcnumber = __( '5', 'lugada' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:','lugada' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rcnumber' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of recent post to show:','lugada' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rcnumber' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'rcnumber' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $rcnumber; ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class RecentPost_Widget

class RandomPost_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /* Register widget with WordPress. */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'randompost_widget', // Base ID
            '(Lugada) Random Post', // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'lugada random post widget.', 'lugada' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /* Front-end display of widget. */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $rndnumber =  $instance['rndnumber'] ;

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        ?>
        <?php 
        echo '<ul>';
        echo lugada_display_random_posts($rndnumber); 
        echo '</ul>';?>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /* Sanitize widget form values as they are saved. */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['rndnumber'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['rndnumber'] );

        return $instance;
    }

    /* Back-end widget form. */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( $instance ) {
            $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
            $rndnumber = esc_attr( $instance[ 'rndnumber' ] );
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'Random post', 'lugada' );
            $rndnumber = __( '5', 'lugada' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:','lugada' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rndnumber' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of random post to show:','lugada' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rndnumber' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'rndnumber' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $rndnumber; ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class RandomPost_Widget

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means that you've got an unclosed string somewhere; the stated line number is usually not meaningful. Also check for things like unpaired parentheses or brackets, and places where you think you're writing in either HTML or PHP but you're actually writing in the other one.